# Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's Expo config (app.config.js or app.json) for production apps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's Expo config (app.config.js or app.json) for production apps, if it's left blank, your app may crash. The scheme does not apply to development in the Expo client but you should add it as soon as you start working with Linking to avoid creating a broken build. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/

I added microsoft sign up to my app with expo and have google sign in with firebase. Now google sign in doesn't work and I get this warning. How do I fix google sign in and remove this error?

Comment: add scheme in your app.json which is your package name exactly. something like this: "scheme":"com.yoursite.yourapp" (this must be same as your package & bundle id.

Comment: working for me after adding a scheme in the app.json.
Thanks @SikandarAliChishty